# Jupyter Notebook: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.pylot'

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I've just received the following error message from inside Jupyter Notebooks.

```
*---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e12bc46e5dd0> in <module>
----> 1 import matplotlib.pylot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.pylot'*
```

But FYI I've already installed matplotlib and I get the following message when I type "pip3 install matplotlib" into Terminal:

```
*Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /Users/mattbrown/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (3.0.3)*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just misspelled the lib name, it’s pyplot, not pylot ;)

Answer (score 0):

Typo, use

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

instead of

```
import matplotlib.pylot as plt
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm so embarrassed! That did the trick. Fixed the typo and went with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```